# how to convert memorystream to filestream in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, filestream, memorystream

I have this code, where I am reading buffers to memory stream and I want to save it to file stream. The problem is that memoryStream.GetBuffer() does not work for my Delphi 7 as it is undeclared identifier.

```
procedure Dictionary.WriteHeaderObj(filename: String);
var MemStream: TMemoryStream;
    i: Integer;
begin
  self.fileName := filename;

  try
    MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      fsOutput := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmCreate);
      try
       MemStream.Write(VAR_META, lengths.VR_META);
       for i:=0 to length(buffers)-1 do
          MemStream.Write(self.buffers[i].b^,self.buffers[i].l^);
       fsOutput.Write(MemStream.GetBuffer(), 0, memoryStream.Position);
      finally
        MemStream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      fsOutput.Free;
    end;
    except
      on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Don't have Delphi 7, but can't you do TFilestream.CopyFrom (MyMemorystream)?

Comment: It seems that it works (thanks). fsOutput.CopyFrom(MemStream, self.buffers[i].l^); . At least - I have compiled it. But yet a question. How to write the FileStream to file then?

Comment: since it is a filestream, you are already writing to the file?

Comment: `TFileStream` already is a file. You provide the path/filename when you create it. As soon as you write to it, you write to the file.

Comment: Ah. I thought that the write() is needed to write to file.

Comment: I don't get it. from your example why do you even need to the `TMemoryStream` and don't write the data directly to the `TFileStream`? You also leaking the `TMemoryStream`.

Comment: @kobik: Because writing data to file in loops is slower than to write it at one go. It's better to write once to HDD than to write 8 times to HDD.

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Any idea why I got ERangeError?

Comment: You got a range error because you accessed an array out of bounds. Unless the individual buffers are very small it will likely be more efficient to write directly to file. Creating yet another copy of the data in memory is wasteful and will hurt performance.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Then how much memory is "very small"? HDD speeds are much slower than RAM memory.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer

Comment: What size are your buffers?

Comment: It depends on situation, but I estimate one buffer size 255 bytes in the case of low requirements.

Comment: Check out [File Buffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-buffering) and [File Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-caching) topics.

Comment: Doesn't make sense without measuring actual performance. And on different environments too. Will behave differently on low memory conditions or with different type of disks. My guess is you'd find you'll be actually slowing the disk. At least read the topic I posted and follow some of the links if you're set on premature optimization.

Comment: It's hard to say but this pattern of pushing data into a memory stream before pushing to another stream is very common anti pattern

Comment: OK, I will use FileStream Only.

Comment: With all the above said, on the other hand, once you have a `TMemoryStream` you could simply use its `SaveToFile` method without using a `TFileStream`. so mixing the two stream types seems pointless.

Comment: @kobik Of course it always depends on how much data is being written. Suppose user wishes to write 5GB to this memory stream...

Comment: @kobik: 5GB can be too much to fit in memory. This procedure is to write header information which can have from 0.15KB to ~200 KB.

Comment: @user1141649 Which is why you've been advised to use `TFileStream` directly, bypassing memory entirely. The same would have applied with your existing solution. If the ultimate destination is a file, then just start with a file.

Comment: @jerry But if you are writing a few bytes at a time then performance is affected because of all the switching between user mode and kernel mode. Which is why we sometimes like to buffer output.

Answer (score 2):

Your code showed several mistakes common to beginners.

1. There really is no need for the `TMemoryStream`. As David said, it hurts performance.
2. It's also not a good idea to write everything to a single `TMemoryStream`, because you may ran into "Out of memory" problem.
3. If the buffer size is really small and using a memory buffer is beneficial, you should do it in two loops - the inner loop writes a certain number of data to the memory stream and the out loop copies the memory stream to the file stream and empty the memory stream.
4. Unfortunately `Capacity` (protected) of `TMemoryStream` is useless because `TMemoryStream` reallocates memory whenever `Size` is changed. Using a sufficiently big `TBytes` avoids memory reallocation but you need to keep track of the length.
5. Why did you just write the header object to the file? Do you intend to append the body to the file later? Append a file is usually a bad idea.
6. Some thing trivial: always pass `string` constants with `const`.
7. Some thing trivial: always start a type name with '`T`'.

Here is how I would do it:

```
procedure TDictionary.SaveHeaderToStream(AStream: TStream);
// You want to write to a stream, not a file. This is more reusable.
// You don't want to put the create/free code here,
// this is more flexible as it can also be used by SaveToStream
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to length(buffers) - 1 do
    AStream.Write(self.buffers[i].b^, self.buffers[i].l^);
end;

procedure TDictionary.SaveHeaderToFile(const Filename: string);
var
  fsOutput: TFileStream;
begin
  fsOutput := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmCreate);
  try
    SaveHeaderToStream(fsOutput);       // fsOutput IS TStream
  finally
    fsOutput.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TDictionary.SaveBodyToStream(AStream: TStream);
begin
  // Codes here
end;

procedure TDictionary.SaveToStream(AStream: TStream);
begin
  SaveHeaderToStream(AStream);
  SaveBodyToStream(AStream);
end;

procedure TDictionary.SaveToFile(const Filename: string);
var
  fsOutput: TFileStream;
begin
  fsOutput := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmCreate);
  try
    SaveToStream(fsOutput);
  finally
    fsOutput.Free;
  end;
end;
```